# Showing $\alpha$ is diagonalisable iff the characteristic of the field does not divide the order of $\alpha$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$. Suppose that $F$ is algebraically closed, and that $\alpha^n=id_{V}$ for some positive integer $n$ while $\alpha^i\neq id_{V}$ for all $1\leq i<n$. Prove that $\alpha$ is diagonalisable if and only if $char(F)\nmid n$.

I have shown the $(\Longleftarrow)$ direction, and I have difficulty in proving if $char(F) | n$, then $\alpha$ is not diagonalisable. Precisely speaking, my problem is as follow:

I tried to prove it in the following way: Since $\alpha$ satisfies the polynomial $p(x)=x^n-1$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $m_{\alpha}(x)$, satisfies $m_{\alpha}(x) | p(x)$. Then on the other hand, let $char(F)=p$, then since $n=kp$ for some positive integer k, $p(x)=x^n-1 = (x^k-1)^p$,so clearly $gcd(p(x), p'(x))\neq1$ where $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$. After that I tried to derive from this result that $gcd(m_{\alpha}(x),m'_{\alpha}(x))$ (where $m'_{\alpha}(x)$ is the derivative of $m_{\alpha}(x)$) will also not equal to 1, and then we can conclude that $\alpha$ is not diagonalisable, but I failed to do so.

Anyone know how derive from it? Or is there any other solution?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there!

You've shown that $p(\alpha)=0$ for $p(x) = (x^k - 1)^p$.  Note that if $\alpha$ is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial can have no repeated factors.  So, we would have to have $q_A \mid (x^k-1)$.

However, from our assumption on $\alpha$, we know that this is not the case.